# What a malicious user could do with a refresh token that cannot be revoked and has 1 year expiry time?

Tags: oauth2, adfs

In ADFS 4.0 a refresh token cannot be renowed without passing through an authorization request flow (asking the user again for credentials) and cannot be revoked.

I'm forced to put a 1 year lifetime for the refresh token to avoid forcing the user to enter his username/password each time the refresh token expires.

**What is the risk if a malicious user steals this refresh token with 1 year expiry time?**

Comment: There is a similar question on best practice for refresh tokens https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170013/oauth-refresh-token-best-practice

Answer (score 1):

If a user or attacker has a refresh token, then they can easily [ask for an access token](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/)  and then access any protected resource. This is the definition of refresh/access tokens. They would also have access for the entire year, though even if they only had it for a day they could do just as much damage. Even with very short expiry times, if they were able to a get a token in the first place, they could replicate what they did the first time to get more tokens.

Now, can anyone get the refresh token? Not unless their computer is already compromised. Doing it remotely is going to be blocked by the ADFS most likely through methods of secure only / HTTP only cookies, forcing them to be transmitted over an encrypted connection and preventing JS leakage (Non web platforms will have similar protections). If someone is able to physically get on the computer and see the cookie, then they might as well just download a keylogger anyway.